# How do I properly update a one to many association using GORM events

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to update a one to many association in Grails using the GORM events `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate`.  Currently the `beforeInsert` seems to be working, but `beforeUpdate` always throws a `TransientObjectException` on the hibernate flush.

The domains are mapped in the following way (an example, but hopefully enough to get the idea):

```
class Part {

   String xml

   static hasMany = [screws: Screws]

   static mapping = {
      screws cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
   }
}

class Screw {
   static belongsTo = Part
}
```

My update and insert essentially do the same thing and this method gets called from both `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` (again a representative example):

```
private void augmentPartWithScrews() {
   screws?.clear()
   Set<Screw> parsedScrews = service.parseXmlAndReturnSetofScrews(xml)
   parsedScrews.each {
      addToScrews(it)
   }
}
```

What I am seeing is that when I create a new Part it works, but when I update Part such that screws are deleted I get a `TransientObjectException` in Hibernate's `ForeignKeys` class.  I did some debugging and found that when creating a new instance of `Part` the objects come into the function `getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved` method as saved instances, but on update they come in as unsaved instances and thus the exception.

This is Grails 2.3.7 and Hibernate plugin 3.6.10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found that trying to do inserts or deletes in the `beforeInsert` or `beforeUpdate` methods can be a real pain. The `withNewSession` is almost always essential since you are effectively trying to modify the session while it's being flushed, causing untold confusion to Hibernate. However, when using `withNewSession`, the `screws` has already been loaded in a different session and will therefore be detached in this new session.

One think you might be able to do in this case is move the logic into a `beforeValidate` method which is not tied into the session flushing behavior. There's a ticket open to add `afterValidate` which is more along the lines of what you want (it's not there yet, though).

However, in this case, it might be best to just reverse the polarity and have a service update/save the new Parts and parse and add the screws instead of trying to put the logic into the domain object.

Comment: Ended up going with this approach.  Thanks!